# angular2 pipe and new data

Tags: angular, socket.io

I am working on an angular pipe to treat and filter logs.

my pipe looks like this

```
import {Injectable, Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'logFilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class logFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
    //console.log(items);

    if (!args || args.length == 0)
    {
        return items;
    }

    return items.filter(item => item.msg.indexOf(args[0]) !== -1);

 }
}
```

html part

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterLog" class="validate" />

 <ul id="messages">
  <li *ngFor="let msg of messages | logFilter:filterLog"> <div class="chip">{{ msg.user }}</div> {{ msg.msg }}</li>
 </ul>
```

new messages can be added throw a socket.io input

this.socket.on('message', function(message, user)
{
    this.messages.push({user:user,msg:message});

}

The filter works fine if I type in the input text but if new messages are added after that, there and not displayed (eg filtered) , I guess there is something to call to trigger the filtering update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular change detection doesn't detect changes inside arrays, only array instance changes (passing a different array instance)

Making the pipe impure

```
@Pipe({
 name: 'logFilter',
 pure: false
})
```

makes Angular2 execute the pipe every time change detection is executed for the component where the pipe is used.

Alternatively you can also use `this arr = this.arr.splice()` after every modification to create a different copy of the array for the change to get notified by Angular.

It depends on the use case and array size which approach is more efficient.